# OS X Lion Mail.app - how to set the Exchange Vacation Notice?

Tags: macos, email, osx-lion, apple-mail

Does anyone know how to set the Exchange Vacation Notice in Mail.app 5.0?

It says on their [feature list](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#mail) that it should work:

```
Exchange 2010 support
Mail, iCal, and Address Book now support Microsoft Exchange 2010.

Exchange vacation notice
Set your Exchange vacation message
from Mail.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show the mailbox list, right-click the Inbox, and select **Get Account Info**. Use the **Out of Office** tab.

Comment: Wow, that is a bit obscure! I would expect it to be in Mail->Preferences.  Oh well, thanks for the answer!